# How to get the value of iterating object

Tags: javascript

I have an object in an object and when I want to iterate over these objects. I succeeded in getting the key but not the value. This is my code:

```js
let oPlaystation = {
    product: {
        Artikelnummer: 15118903,
        Fabrikantcode: 845784935,
        Merk: "Sony",
        Garantie: "2 jaar",
        Garantietype: "Carry-in-garantie"
    },
    algemeen: {
        platform: "Playstation 4",
        Aanbevolen_voor_virtual_reality: false,            
    },
    opslagcapaciteit: {
        Totale_opslagcapaciteit: "1000 GB",
        Werkgeheugen_uitbreidbaar: true,
        Maximale_capaciteit_geheugenkaart: "8000 GB"
    },
    Bedrade_aansluitingen : {
        Netwerkaansluiting: true,
        HDMI_ansluiting: true,
        USB_aansluiting: true,
        USB_versie: 3.0,
        Aantal_USB_poorten: 2
    }
}

let output = "";
Object.keys(oPlaystation).forEach(section => {    
    output += '<h3>' + section + '</h3>';        
    output += '<dl class="product-specs">';
    let features = Object.keys(oPlaystation[section]);
    features.forEach(attr => {    
    output += '<div class="product-specs__list-item">';
    output += '<dt class="product-specs__item-title">' + attr + '</dt>';
    output += '<dd class="product-specs__item-spec">' + features[attr] + '</dd>';
    output += '</div>';    
    });
    output += '</dl>';
});
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", output);
```

Now I get undefined back in the `<dd>` element as value. Does anyknow how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you for including nearly all the necessary code to replicate the problem. Take a look at the edit I made, which made it easy to see the problem by making a *runnable* example in the question. [Here's how to do that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) (for next time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the object with the first key and then the second key

```
oPlaystation[section][attr]
```

instead of

```
features[attr]
```

```js
var oPlaystation = {
    product: {
        Artikelnummer: 15118903,
        Fabrikantcode: 845784935,
        Merk: "Sony",
        Garantie: "2 jaar",
        Garantietype: "Carry-in-garantie"
    },
    algemeen: {
        platform: "Playstation 4",
        Aanbevolen_voor_virtual_reality: false,            
    },
    opslagcapaciteit: {
        Totale_opslagcapaciteit: "1000 GB",
        Werkgeheugen_uitbreidbaar: true,
        Maximale_capaciteit_geheugenkaart: "8000 GB"
    },
    Bedrade_aansluitingen : {
        Netwerkaansluiting: true,
        HDMI_ansluiting: true,
        USB_aansluiting: true,
        USB_versie: 3.0,
        Aantal_USB_poorten: 2
    }
},
    output = '';


Object.keys(oPlaystation).forEach(section => {    
    output += '<h3>' + section + '</h3>';        
    output += '<dl class="product-specs">';
    let features = Object.keys(oPlaystation[section]);
    features.forEach(attr => {    
        output += '<div class="product-specs__list-item">';
        output += '<dt class="product-specs__item-title">' + attr + '</dt>';
        output += '<dd class="product-specs__item-spec">' + oPlaystation[section][attr] + '</dd>';
        output += '</div>';    
    });
    output += '</dl>';
});

document.body.innerHTML += output;
```

Comment: That was the fix! Thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys() return a array of the keys of object, so you cant access the data in an array by use key.
you can use for-in loop to replace Object.keys,like:

```
    for (const section in oPlaystation) {
        output += '<h3>' + section + '</h3>';
        output += '<dl class="product-specs">';
        let features = oPlaystation[section];
        for (const attr in features) {
            output += '<div class="product-specs__list-item">';
            output += '<dt class="product-specs__item-title">' + attr + '</dt>';
            output += '<dd class="product-specs__item-spec">' + features[attr] + '</dd>';
            output += '</div>';    
        }
        output += '</dl>';
    }
```